# SELECT from tableA if not in tableC

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, union

I have a view, which selects data from TableA (TableA will be decommissioned once we migrated it all). We are creating a new table, called `TABLEC`, where we'll be migrating all the data from TableA to TableC in the future.

- The reason we are doing this, it's because `tableA` is very old and bad designed.
- At the moment, `tableA` is being used only for old records. All new data that would be inserted into `tableA` is already going to `tableC` via application.
- I cannot change any table's schema.
- The view can be changed to use `CTE`, IF, it is at least as fast as it's now.
- `path` is not a real path, but it's a regular expression. It will be something like: `/file/account/[0-9]+` <-- after this there are some possibilites, it can be several different words (such as: attach/assigned/etc).

While we don't migrate all the data from `tableA` to `tableC`, we need the view to be compatible with both tables, as there is already new data going to `tableC`.

View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW path_view AS
  SELECT split_part(n1.path::text, '/'::text, 18)::integer AS id,
         split_part(n1.path::text, '/'::text, 14)::integer AS clientid,
         lower(n1.md5::text)::character(32) AS md5, 0 AS cont,
         '00000000-1000-1000-3000-600000000000'::uuid AS guid,
         n1.bytes AS byte_count,
         n1.last_modified AS last_modified
  FROM   tablea n1
  JOIN   tableb s2 
  ON     s2.path = n1.path;
```

-- `tablea` and `tableb` are pretty much the same; as said before, it was bad designed.

I need the view to do:

- Look if the requested data is in the new table `tableC`
- **IF NOT**, then go to `tableA` and get the data

QUESTION:

How can I do that? I tried with `UNION ALL` but it's very slow.

`\d tableC`:

```
Table "public.tablec"
--------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
id            | integer                     | not null default nextval('tablec_id_seq'::regclass)
e_type        | integer                     | not null
e_id          | bigint                      | 
e_variation   | character varying(16)       | not null
path          | character varying(255)      | not null
name          | character varying(255)      | not null
size          | bigint                      | not null
md5           | md5_hash                    | not null
modified_date | timestamp without time zone | default statement_timestamp()
created_date  | timestamp without time zone | default statement_timestamp()
clientid      | bigint                      | not null
f_id          | bigint                      |
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify tablea schema?

Comment: @McNets - Not possible, unfortunately!

Comment: Can build a TableA_Copy, normalize your current data, add some index and then join this new table with tableC?

Comment: @McNets no. `tablea` is 4TB large. Cannot do that.

Comment: Obviously `path` is the field that join both tables, but is the field used to search for records on tablec too?

Comment: yes. it is. path would be the right "way" to check in tablec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO I think that the fast way on this case is looking first at TableC, and if not exists on TableC, search the record on TableA/B.

I've set up a small example:

> ```
> create table tableA (id int, path varchar(30), other_things int);
> create table tableB (id int, path varchar(30), other_things int);
> create table tableC (id int, path varchar(30), other_things int);
> insert into tableA values 
> (1, '/file1/account1/0001', 1),(2, '/file1/account2/0001', 1),
> (3, '/file1/account1/0002', 1),(4, '/file2/account1/0002', 1),
> (5, '/file1/account2/0003', 1),(6, '/file2/account1/0003', 1);
> insert into tableB values 
> (1, '/file1/account1/0001', 1),(2, '/file1/account2/0001', 1),
> (3, '/file1/account1/0002', 1),(4, '/file1/account2/0002', 1),
> (5, '/file2/account1/0003', 1),(6, '/file1/account1/0003', 1);
> insert into tableC values 
> (1, '/file3/account3/0004', 1),(2, '/file3/account4/0004', 1),
> (3, '/file4/account3/0005', 1),(4, '/file3/account4/0005', 1),
> (5, '/file3/account3/0006', 1),(6, '/file4/account3/0006', 1);
> ```

As far as you are using a regular expression `/file/account/[0-9]+` to filter records, you could use the operator `~`. ([POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP))

But have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12459689/3270427) of [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter) about using regular expressions, just in case you could add some extra index to your table.

I've used a function because it allows me to use IF EXISTS (). It only search the record on TableA if it doesn't exists on TableC. Obviously you can change the search order.

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getABC (MyPath VARCHAR) 
>  RETURNS TABLE (
>  ID text,
>  client_id text,
>  other int
> ) 
> AS $$
> BEGIN
>
>    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableC WHERE path ~ $1) THEN
>         RETURN QUERY SELECT split_part(t1.path::text, '/'::text, 2)::text AS id,
>                             split_part(t1.path::text, '/'::text, 3)::text AS clientid, 
>                             t1.other_things
>                      FROM   TableC t1
>                      WHERE  t1.path ~ $1;
>     ELSE
>         RETURN QUERY SELECT split_part(t1.path::text, '/'::text, 2)::text AS id,
>                             split_part(t1.path::text, '/'::text, 3)::text AS clientid, 
>                             t1.other_things
>                      FROM   TableA t1
>                      JOIN   TableB t2
>                      ON     t1.path = t2.path
>                      WHERE  t1.path ~ $1;
>     END IF;
>
>     RETURN;
> END; $$ 
> LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
> ```

Now you can search for a specific path on this way:

> This records are fetched from TableC
>
> ```
> select * from getABC('/file3/account4/[0-9]+');
> ```
>
> ```
> id    | client_id | other
> :---- | :-------- | ----:
> file3 | account4  |     1
> file3 | account4  |     1
> ```

> This records are fetched from TableA
>
> ```
> select * from getABC('/file1/account1/[0-9]+');
> ```
>
> ```
> id    | client_id | other
> :---- | :-------- | ----:
> file1 | account1  |     1
> file1 | account1  |     1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=eb1f9ffa7aac79d6575652be6d1fb2a3)*

Comment: It is a very good idea using `UNION`. However, it is very slow. will need to work on this. Probably will need more `WHERE` between `tablea` and `tablec``

Comment: Have you tried the function? in fact union only affect rows where not exist in table c

Comment: is it possible to call a function from a view?

Comment: Check it here: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=555c15a00581e7be337df5315c6e51eb

Comment: Question: `select * from getABC('100/0005');` - I don't know what the path will be. it has: `~ '^/file/account/[0-9]+'` - How can I add that to the function? / The path will always be like that, where /account/integer.

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_view AS
select * from getABC('^/file/account/[0-9]+');` -----> Does not work

Comment: ah, it is not a real path, is a regular expression. well, late here, I'll try to add this to the answer tomorrow. BTW, you should add this to the question or add a new question about this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58549/discussion-between-patrick-b-and-mcnets).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a full outer join with coalesce on each column.

I haven't had a chance to test this but something like:

```
    SELECT 
    split_part(COALESCE(n1.path,n3.path)::text, '/'::text, 18)::integer AS id,
    split_part(COALESCE(n1.path,n3.path)::text, '/'::text, 14)::integer AS clientid,
    lower(COALESCE(n1.md5,n3.md5)::text)::character(32) AS md5, 0 AS cont,
    '00000000-1000-1000-3000-600000000000'::uuid AS guid,
    COALESCE(n1.bytes,n3.bytes) AS byte_count,
    COALESCE(n1.last_modified,n3.last_modified) AS last_modified
      FROM tablea n1
      JOIN tableb s2 ON s2.path = n1.path
      FULL OUTER JOIN tablec n3 ON ... = ...
```

Comment: `tableb` is not the new table.

Comment: Answer edited - I wasn't sure on the PK or which columns you would want to join on, but would more than likely be the id column.

Comment: The data that is into `tablec` is not in `tablea`. Remember that `tablec` will replace `tablea` and currently has only new records, the old records are still in `tablea`. So i can't really join them. Only for clientid.

Comment: That's why the use of a full outer join is useful - both tables will be returned and coalesce can take care of which data to bring back. In this situation - perhaps the order of the coalesce should be n3, n1? This would mean if the data is in Table C (n3), use that, otherwise use table A (n1)